# Fluentvalidation inject business object to validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0

I am using fluentvalidation and use structuremap to inject validators for actions in asp.net mvc3. I have problems to inject my business objects to validator objects. I get an error like this:

{"StructureMap Exception Code:  202\nNo Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Suggestion.Biz.BO.ISubjectBO, Suggestion.Biz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}

How can i inject SubjectBO to SubjectValidator?

SubjectValidator:

```
public class SubjectValidator : AbstractValidator<SUBJECT>
{
    private ISubjectBO _subjectBO;
    public SubjectValidator(ISubjectBO subjectBO)
    {
        _subjectBO = subjectBO;
        Custom(x=>{
            if(!_subjectBO.CanUpdate(x))
            return new ValidationFailure(null, "error msg");
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

SuggestionValidationRegistry:

```
public class SuggestionValidationRegistry : Registry
{
    public SuggestionValidationRegistry()
    {

        For<IValidator<SUBJECT>>().Singleton().Use<SubjectValidator>();
        ValidatorOptions.ResourceProviderType = typeof(ValidationResources);
    }
}
```

StructureMapValidatorFactory:

```
public class StructureMapValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {

        return ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType) as IValidator;
    }
}
```

App_start:

```
        ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => cfg.AddRegistry(new SuggestionValidationRegistry()));
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => provider.ValidatorFactory = new StructureMapValidatorFactory());
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Yes i configure at app_start
SuggestionBizRegistry :

```
public class BizRegistry : Registry
{
    public BizRegistry()
    {
        For<IAwardTypeBO>().Use<AwardTypeBO>();
        For<IQuoteBO>().Use<QuoteBO>();
        For<ISubjectBO>().Use<SubjectBO>();
        For<IContestBO>().Use<ContestBO>();
        For<IApplicationBO>().Use<ApplicationBO>();
        For<IScreenBO>().Use<ScreenBO>();
    }
}
```

App_start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ConfigureStructureMap();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        EFUnitOfWorkFactory.SetObjectContext(() => new SuggestionModel());


        UnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkFactory = new EFUnitOfWorkFactory();


    }

    private static void ConfigureStructureMap()
    {
        IContainer container = new Container(x =>
        {
            x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use<StructureMapControllerActivator>();
            x.AddRegistry(new BizRegistry());                
        });
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
        ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => cfg.AddRegistry(new SuggestionValidationRegistry()));
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => provider.ValidatorFactory = new StructureMapValidatorFactory(container));
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not configured constructor parameter `ISubjectBO subjectBO` when configuring `SubjectValidator` injection

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validator factory as explained in [this thread](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/265738).

Comment: I have an validator factory  StructureMapValidatorFactory(): public class StructureMapValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
    {
        public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
        {
            return ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType) as IValidator;
        }
    }

Comment: @Yorgo, have you configured an instance for the `ISubjectBO` interface?